# Can I use one custom created UIViewController to populating cells text value of parent UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I have created one custom `ViewController` named `SetValueVC` with `UITextView` in it. During creating new product in my app I display `UITableViewController` with cell that need to be specify. If user click on some cell I display my `UIViewController` as `detailView` to allow setting parent `UITableViewCells` `detailLabel`.text value.  I know how to pass data from child view by using delegate but how it works when there is for example 10 rows? Should I create 10 delegates methods for every row or just create object of `SetValueVC` for every row in `didselectForRow` method and use just one delegate method ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be an answer : Work with a **singleton** and use your model in your `ViewController` and your `UITableViewController`

in the `.h` :

```
+(MyModel *)shared;
```

in the `.m` :

static MyModel *myModel;

```
@implementation MyModel

+(MyModel *) shared{
    if (nil != myModel) {
        return myModel;
    }

    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        myModel = [[MyModel alloc] init];
    });
    return myModel;
}
```

In this way, you can access to your model anywhere of your app.

Hope that will help.

Comment: I never used singleton because I read some unflattering posts about them, but I will try, thanks for your answer